# show submit button when clicking textarea

Tags: javascript

I have number of textareas.

When I click on textarea its shape expand perfectly. than I try to add code that will show the SUBMIT button (after the clicking).

My code works, but not well- I need to click number of times until the button appear.

Why is that?

```
echo "<form id='addComment".$fIndex['id']."' action='#' method='post' >";
    echo "<p style='margin: 0 15px 0 10px'><textarea class='expandTextarea' refID='".$fIndex['id']."'></textarea></p>";
    echo "<p><a href='#' class='addComment button3d' refID='".$fIndex['id']."' id='addCommentButton".$fIndex['id']."' style='display: none'>Submit</a></p>";
echo "</form>";




$(function() {
    $(".expandTextarea").focus(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var refID = element.attr("refID");
//      alert(refID);



        $('textarea.expandTextarea').focus(function () {
            $(this).animate({ height: "200px" }, 500); 
        //  $('.addComment').show();
            $('#addCommentButton' +refID).show();
        });




    });
});
```

Comment: Because the second `.focus()` is inside the first one so you need to first focus once to get the second focus handled active, then unfocus and focus again to trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

To get both actions working with a single focus:

```
$(function() {
    $(".expandTextarea").focus(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var refID = element.attr("refID");
        element.animate({ height: "200px" }, 500); 
        $('#addCommentButton' +refID).show();
    });
});
```